# In a Matplotlib plot with time on the x-axis, how to make the major and minor axis labels not overlap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a histogram from an `pandas` DataFrame column, `'Time'`, which has major tick marks every day and minor ones every hour, with labels for both at different 'offsets'.

So far, what I have is

```
import datetime
import random
import dateutil.parser
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

start = dateutil.parser.parse("1 January 2019")
end = dateutil.parser.parse("3 January 2019")

data = [start + (end - start) * random.random() for _ in range(1000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Time'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hist(df['Time'], bins=mdates.drange(start, end, datetime.timedelta(hours=1)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.set_ylabel('Counts per hour')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which leads to a plot with overlapping labels on the x-axis:

[image]

I believe I could increase the spacing between the hour tick marks themselves by using an `RRuleLocator` for every 3 hours, say, instead of the `HourLocator`. But how would I prevent the hour label at midnight every day from overlapping with the label for the day's date? Is there a way to offset these two sets of labels vertically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course only one of many possible options: I would set a padding of the order of the fontsize to the major ticklabels.

```
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="major", pad=12)
```

Complete code:

```
import datetime
import random
import dateutil.parser
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

start = dateutil.parser.parse("1 January 2019")
end = dateutil.parser.parse("3 January 2019")

data = [start + (end - start) * random.random() for _ in range(1000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Time'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hist(df['Time'], bins=mdates.drange(start, end, datetime.timedelta(hours=1)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator((0,6,12,18,)))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.set_ylabel('Counts per hour')

ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="major", pad=12)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]